# Redirect Input and Output to and from buffer

Tags: shell, vim, command, buffer, neovim

Is it possible to redirect the input and output of a **shell** command to and from vim **buffer**?

Intended behavior is similar to the Emacs `shell-command-on-region` for input and redirecting the output to a buffer as emacs does. The input and output buffers are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this description](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html#Shell) of `shell-command-on-region`:

> `M-|` *cmd* `<RET>`
>
> Run the shell command *cmd* with region contents as input; optionally replace the region with the output (`shell-command-on-region`).

the built-in way to run a command with the selected lines as input is `:help :w_c`:

```
:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}
            Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
            (note the space in front of the '!'). [...]
```

and the built-in way to replace the selection with the input of a command is `:help !`:

```
:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]               *:range!*
            Filter {range} lines through the external program
            {filter}. [...]
```

Both methods have slight alternatives, don't be afraid to scroll around when reading an help section.

[image]

Comment: I see. But i don't want to replace the text of the input. I want to have input in a separate buffer and output in a separate buffer.

Comment: But that's not what `shell-command-on-region` do so why mention it? For that you will have to write some code yourself or use one of the  solutions found in the "scripts" section of http://www.vim.org.

Comment: I wrote elisp code to achieve that but i am not sure how to achieve it in lua. That's why i wrote the input and output buffers are not the same

Comment: Lua? What does Lua have to with it?

Comment: sorry i mean in vim